# Why is a check for an object passing through this if condition and then raising an AttributeError because it doesn't exist?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got models that look like this:

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    pass  # there's obviously more to this but for the sake of this question...

class Deal(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(
        Agent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

Inside the `save` method of the `Deal`, I have some code that updates the metrics of the `Agent` that looks like this:

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(
        Agent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )

    #  ... other code ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.agent):
            try:
                self.agent.closing_success_rate = self.get_agent_closing_success_rate()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

And when there is not an `Agent` connected to the deal, I get the error:

> "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'closing_success_rate'"

How is the if condition that checks if the `Agent` exists passing only to later throw an error because it doesn't exist?

Comment: Likely it isn't. Likely the error is in the `get_agent_closing_success_rate` method.

Comment: But it's saying `NoneType` doesn't have the attribute; doesn't that mean that the object that doesn't exist doesn't have that attribute? Because the `closing_success_rate` isn't referenced in the `get_agent_closing_success_rate` method.